# Local DNS address not removed by update-resolv-conf when connecting to OpenVPN via terminal

Tags: dns, openvpn

So my problem is the following - I'm connecting to an OpenVPN server on Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) via the following command:

```
sudo openvpn --config /home/...../VPN_file.ovpn
```

I've also added the following lines to the .ovpn file to prevent DNS leaks:

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

What I found was that the local DNS address is not being removed during the initialization of the VPN, just the VPN DNS server added to /etc/resolv.conf (by local DNS server I mean my ISP one):

```
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver VPN DNS Server
nameserver LOCAL DNS Server
```

Also the following appears in the terminal during the initialization:

```
Sun Jun 21 21:47:42 2020 /sbin/ip route add ......./32 via LOCAL_DNS_Server
Sun Jun 21 21:47:42 2020 /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via VPN_DNS_Server
Sun Jun 21 21:47:42 2020 /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via VPN_DNS_Server
```

All the above results in DNS leaks, which I want to avoid. On my other Linux machine doing the same thing removes the local DNS when VPN is turned on, I don't know why this is not the case here.

Anyone had a similar problem? Any suggestions to fix it?

Thank you in advance!